# Not able to extent 3rd monitor using USB C docking

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, usb-c, docking

Hi Folks the issue that I have is that using a USB C docking I'm able to get my laptop and 2 monitors to work but the 3rd monitor only as a mirror of the second external monitor, so I was wondering what I can do in order to get it to work:

from dmesg when I disconnect and connect the docking whit all the 2 monitor attached(by the way the one working normally is a HDMI and the 3rd which is just working as a mirror is connected through VGA):

```
[56652.087820] hid-generic 0005:046D:B342.000B: input,hidraw6: BLUETOOTH HID v42.00 Keyboard [Keyboard K380] on d0:c6:37:64:26:d8
[57847.906690] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906702] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906752] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906761] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906825] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906834] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906877] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.906885] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.935264] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.935274] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.935281] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57847.935288] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57849.782197] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57849.782211] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57849.782219] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57849.782227] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57850.722936] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[57850.722942] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[57863.222406] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[57863.382923] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=177a, idProduct=963d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[57863.382931] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[57863.382936] usb 1-5: Product: Billboard Device
[57863.382940] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: EXPSM USB
[57863.382944] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 0001
[57863.391244] hid-generic 0003:177A:963D.000C: hiddev0,hidraw7: USB HID v1.10 Device [EXPSM USB Billboard Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
[57865.275799] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 10
[57865.403873] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.403913] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.404060] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.404089] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.404223] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.404251] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.404378] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.404405] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.923607] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.923644] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.923674] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
[57865.923696] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected

djr@djacamo840:~$
```

also looks like nothing happens when I unplug the vga excepts the amount of this lines:

```
[57865.923696] evdi: [D] evdi_detect:94 (dev=0) poll connector state: disconnected
```

Comment: You are really using Ubuntu 12.04? IF yes, you should update your system. It's not longer supported since 2017-04-28.

Comment: my bad, that was a typo 20.04 is what I'm using.

Comment: Ok, thats not so worste, then Ubuntu 12.04 . 
What kind of hardware do you use? Which graficcard? Which is the Screen with the problem when you use USB-C? What kind of docking station is it?

Comment: Are you sure your graphics card even supports 3 monitors? If not, that could be the reason why the third monitor can only mirror the second one.

Comment: I have a HP Elitbook 840 G5, and yes I have another docking in my office which allows me to do the same(an official HP docking), I have Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2). the docking is a unbranded docking from amazon.